# URL rewriting via Wordpress Rewrite or .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

**JUMP TO EDIT8 TO SEE HOW I SOLVED THIS**

---

Let's say I have a Wordpress blog: `www.animals.com`. I have a certain PHP file in my theme directory: `www.animals.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/db.php`. Also, I have a custom template for that page, so I create a new page in the Wordpress administration panel to show `db.php`: `www.animals.com/database`.

So if I want to read something about lions, I just go to: `www.animals.com/database/?animal=lion` (because that's the way I decided to write the PHP, inserting the value from $_GET['animal'] into the query, using PDO etc.).

**Now, I would like to access `www.animals.com/database/?animal=lion` as `www.animals.com/lion`.**

Should I use .htaccess or Wordpress Rewrite? Where should I place my .htaccess, in the root of the Wordpress folder (with wp-config.php and those files) or in my theme directory?

The one from the root has `RewriteBase /` and stuff from Wordpress by default. What should I write to achieve what I want? Should I put it before or after the existing code?

**EDIT**: this is my **public_html** .htaccess and this is what I **really** want to do:
I have a website: `www.domain.com` and when you type this `http://www.domain.com/dios/?dios=agni` it shows you the info about the god Agni. I would like to type `www.domain.com/dioses/agni` to access the info about the god Agni. The PHP file is in `www.domain.com/wp-content/themes/smitespain/dios.php`
It's not working x_x

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^dioses/(\w*)$ dios/?dios=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

**EDIT2**: i'm using multisite **(check EDIT4)**, and again, /database/ /dios/ and /dioses/ are **not** actual folders I created, thats the name for the page I created in Wordpress. The thing is, now it shows the name of the god in the tab title :S that means the variable $_GET['dios'] is set, but it doesnt load the file (dios.php) =/

**EDIT3**: I need to access domain.com/dios/?dios=agni specifically, because thats the URL that will let the PHP file (dios.php) to load get_header() from wordpress, so i cant access the file directly

**EDIT4**: I decided to remove the multisite thing

**EDIT5**: these are the Wordpress pages I have:
`domain.com/dioses/` for `(www.domain.com/wp-content/themes/smitespain/dioses.php)`
`domain.com/dios/?dios=thor` for `(www.domain.com/wp-content/themes/smitespain/dios.php)`

**EDIT6**: i was reading something in the wordpress codex..and realized that, if i wanna go to `domain.com/dioses` i can access it by going to `domain.com/index.php?pagename=dioses` or `domain.com/?pagename=dioses`
So, i added this between the `Rewritebase /` and the next rule: `RewriteRule example/test ?pagename=dioses` and `domain.com/example/test` redirects me to `domain.com/dioses` but it also changes the url in the address bar :(
The thing is, if i try this: `RewriteRule example/test ?pagename=dios&dios=thor` it will send me to the page 'dios' without the '?dios=thor'

**EDIT7**: i started using wordpress rewrite, i added this to my theme's functions.php:

```
function my_rewrite_rules() {  
    add_rewrite_rule(  
        'blah',
        'index.php?pagename=dios&dios=agni',  
        'top'  
    );  
}  
add_action( 'init', 'my_rewrite_rules' );
```

and again..it loads the page dios, without the ?dios=agni

**EDIT8**: and finally, I managed to make it work =)
the first thing i needed to know is, the new `?dios=XXXX` will be no longer available to `$_GET['dios']` instead, you need to call `$wp_query->query_vars['dios']` so i added this to my theme's functions.php

```
function add_query_vars($new_var) {
$new_var[] = "dios";
return $new_var;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');

function add_rewrite_rules($rules) {
$new_rules = array('([^/]+)' => 'index.php?pagename=dios&dios=$matches[1]');
$rules = $new_rules + $rules;
return $rules;
}
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');
```

i make sure `$wp_query->query_vars['dios']` is actually set
then i just add the regular rule

Answer (score 3):

There is another way to solve it, without touching WordPress.

Add to .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^lion /indexw.php?pagename=db&dios=$1 [L,E=URI:/detail/]
```

Create file indexw.php:

```
<?php $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] = $_SERVER["REDIRECT_URI"]; include("index.php");
```

How it works? mod_rewrite sets REDIRECT_URI as specified in E=URI:value argument.
indexw.php just overwrites REQUEST_URI with correct value (Thanks to Ravi Thapliyal for an insight on this)

Answer (score 1):

WordPress puts a global redirect on root for everything unidentified i.e. not an existing file or a folder to its `/index.php`. You on the other hand now want to redirect them to `?animal=unidentified`. So, unless the list of animal keywords is fixed any solution proposed could mess up your WordPress.

If you had like 10-odd animals you could add them like below to your .htaccess (at root /)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(lion|leopard|tiger|dog|cat)/?$ database/?animal=$1 [NC,L]

# WordPress rules come here
```

For 40-odd animals I would suggest you to have a directory (need not exist) prefix for your animals.

```
RewriteRule ^a/(.+?)/?$ database/?animal=$1 [NC,L]
```

This would redirect any `/a/critter` to `database/?animal=critter` and you won't have to add them to your .htaccess manually any more. You could also have both the rules co-exist so that if you haven't modified .htaccess for `/panther` yet you could still access it at `/a/panther`.

***EDIT:***
Okay, I looked into it and it isn't possible without writing a PHP script to intercept this request and forward it to `index.php`. Here's how mutisite works: since, none of your rewrites match it goes to `index.php`; the entry point for WordPress's php code. Somewhere deep, the code checks the REQUEST_URI header to see if it matches one of your multisites (`/dios`) and if it does, forwards the request to the page configured (`dios.php`).

When we do an .htaccess redirect for `/dioses/agni` we're able to hit `index.php` (by removing the [L]) but the REQUEST_URI header still remains the same (/dioses/agni) and it has no mulisite configured for it. Hence, the redirection fails.

Comment: I managed to write this in the .htaccess file within the them directory: RewriteRule ^(\w*)$ db.php?animal=$1 so now I can access www.animals.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/db.php?animal=lion as www.animals.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/lion Can I do something with that url then? Like turning it to www.animals.com/lion from that url? How should I do this if I wanted to use a fixed list?

Comment: I'm talking about root "domain.com/lion". If "domain.com/someanimalyoudontwant" was being redirect by wordpress nicely it won't happen now.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I can't really understand it :S

Comment: Ohh I see, and yes, i'd like to type in the address bar: animals.com/lion to access animals.com/database/?animal=lion So if I have an 'About' page, and I type animals.com/about there would be a conflict or something like that between the actual 'About' page and ?animal=about, right? How could I do this using a fixed list?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to make you understand. How long is the list? It may get impractical after a point. On my coffee break now.. :) I'll post a sample with three to four animals in some time.

Comment: Well.. right now I would like to write 36 animals, and I would add a new one every 2 weeks xD Thanks =)

Comment: Answer updated with two different approaches. Second one is better.

Comment: Wait, so if instead of animals.com/lion I use animals.com/example/lion that would work? I mean, no conflict then? I would make sure, example is not a word used from either Wordpress or any other page I have..

Comment: Yes, you can but I suggest going for a shorter prefix. If you go for something longer then I suggest to use it to your advantage and have your links as `/canine/dog`, /bird/sparrow`,`/fish/salmon` etc. You could have your multiple rules co-exist as well.

Comment: I really need them to be grouped to 1 "folder". Check the update I did.. and thank you so much for your patiance :)

Comment: No, you misunderstood. You'll still have a single physical folder (database) but different links (which are now more search engine friendly) pointing to it. It's okay, you can take this up later as well! Let's fix your site first. :)

Comment: Do I need to create the folder 'dioses' in my public_html directory? The .htaccess should be above the folder public_html, as well as the folder 'dioses'?

Comment: Remove the L from your rule and keep it [NC]. Report what happens.

Comment: Removed it and went to http://smitespain.com/dioses/agni it redirects me to http://smitespain.com Check edit 2, just in case..

Comment: How does /dios/?dios=agni work? I'm a little lost on multisite.

Comment: www.smitespain.com/dios/dios=agni shows you www.smitespain.com/wp-content/themes/smitespain/dios.php?dios=agni I created a new page, set a custom template for that file and chose to call it www.smitespain.com/dios (for www.smitespain.com/wp-content/themes/smitespain/dios.php) I hope that makes sense xD That doesnt really do much with multisite :P

Comment: Okay, as a workaround set your rule to `wp-content/themes/smitespain/dios.php?dios=$1 [NC,L]` Let me know if that works. I'll check up on multisite to see if I can recommend something better.

Comment: That is what I could do by myself, already tried that but there's one problem, if I access a PHP file directly, it wont load the header, the footer.. and all the WP stuff =/ that's why im using the custom template, to let me use get_header() for example :S EDIT: this says something about multisite and rewriting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790207/htaccess-rewrite-wordpress-multisite

Comment: Okay, let me see what I can find. I'll notify when I post an update. Till then please remove your domain name from your .htaccess for security reasons. (Remove the exposing comments as well.) Call it `sp` or something.

Comment: You still left some `highlighted` :) Anyways, just for my info do you have pretty permalinks on?

Comment: Yes, I selected Post name: http://www.smitespain.com/blog/sample-post/ (.com/blog/%postname%/)

Comment: Okay, I looked into it and it ain't possible without writing a PHP script. The way mutisite works is that since none of your rewrites match it goes to index.php which is the entry point for wordpress's php code. Some where in this code it checks the REQUEST_URI header to see if it matches one of your multisites like /dios and then forwards the request to dios.php.

Comment: When we do an .htaccess redirect we're able to hit index.php (by removing the L) but the REQUEST_URI header still remains /dioses/agni which has no mulisite configured for it and hence the whole thing fails.

Comment: So there's no way to do this? Even using a fixed list? Would it be posible using Wordpress rewrite? Or trying to do this to the multisite network, instead of one of the blogs?

Comment: I decided to remove the multisite thing

Comment: Hey, I checked your soln. Didn't understand anything but it sure looks cool :) Glad to know you finally got it working. Sorry, I was offline and couldn't be of much help. If I knew you're this good with PHP I would have shared the pointers on the new script yesterday itself. It would have made use of curl to work its mojo with request headers.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^www\.animals\.com/lion$ /www.animals.com/database/?animal=lion [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Just use this code. I hope that it will works.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't use signatures or taglines in your posts. Every post you make is already "signed" with your standard user card, which links directly back to your user page. Your user page belongs to you — fill it with interesting information about your interests, cool stuff you've worked on, or whatever else you like! It might be worth taking a look at the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), specially the [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) page.

Answer (score 0):

URL rewriting wouldn't work for me, neither by calling `add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', function() {})`, nor by calling `add_rewrite_rule()`. Apparently that was because filter `'rewrite_rules_array'` was never triggered when opening frontend website pages, so the rewrites weren't generated.

The solution was to go to admin area and just open page Settings -> Permalinks. I need to do that every time I want to change my rewrites.

I don't know if vanilla Wordpress works like that, this is probably caused by an plugin/theme a have installed.