# URL Rewriting in Wordpress htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've built a Wordpress site that has a product page which retrieves product info from an external system using the querystring id passed in. So **www.domain.com/product/?id=n** loads the Wordpress product page which then loads the product info using the id.

This works fine.

However, I want to rewrite this URL so that:

**www.domain.com/product/productname/id** retrieves **www.domain.com/product/?id=n**

When I add the following to htaccess, the page returns a 404 because it doesn't exist in Wordpress.

**RewriteRule ^product/productname/(.*)$ ^product/?id=$1 [L]**

Does anyone know how to write this rule in such a way that it doesn't get hijacked by Wordpress rewriting?

Comment: Nothing to add other than I'm looking to do something similar and would love to hear if anyone has any insights on this...

Answer (score 0):

After doing some additional searching, I've found some links that may help you get started. The secret lies in WordPress's `add_rewrite_rules`hook. Haven't tried these myself yet, but looks promising:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule
- [URL rewriting via Wordpress Rewrite or .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16664579/url-rewriting-via-wordpress-rewrite-or-htaccess-solved)
- http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-url-rewrite/
- http://matty.co.za/2009/11/custom-url-rewrites-in-wordpress/