# .htaccess rule to rewrite query string to a path

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm looking for a way to have the URL
site.com/collection/name
serve the content that is actually located at...
site.com/collection/?collection_name=name

The website is running on WordPress, and is currently using the default .htaccess rules located in the root:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Because it's on WordPress, it's currently looking for a page /collection/name that doesn't exist, and produces a 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be an index file under the folder "name"

If so, you can try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/$ /collection/name/index.php
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ /collection/?collection_name=$1
```

This is a generic rule that works in many similar occasions. Modify it to suit your website...

Comment: The "name" part has to be dynamic though, so there wouldn't be a real folder called "name".

Comment: In that case, you could change the third line to: "RewriteRule ^/$ /collection/index.php"... That is of course if there is an index.php file in the folder "collection"...

Comment: It's WordPress so "/collection" is actually a page, not a folder. If I create a "collection" folder it breaks. I think I would need the rule to be in the .htaccess of the root.

Comment: @Jamie I think so too, you should include these rules in your root .htaccess file. In that case you should fo course omit the first two lines (since they already exist there). But, I must say that I have minimal to none Wordpress experience, since I usually code my projects from scratch. I did a google search and located 2 interesting articles: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/htaccess-rewriterule-2 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16664579/url-rewriting-via-wordpress-rewrite-or-htaccess-solved ...You may want to check them out or google "wordpress .htaccess rules" for more results...